# Can't open Software Center

Tags: system, pantheon-terminal, apt

I am a beginner on Linux so I don't know what went wrong but the Software Center wont open anymore, if I click it it will open and close immediately. Also, on the top bar it will appear the message on the attached picture. [image: error message]

Now I cannot install any application, it wont let me install it from the terminal because it will says "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." or "Type '“deb' is not known on line 59 in source list /etc/apt/sources.listE: The list of sources could not be read."

Comment: Did you edit your sources.list manually?

Comment: Is there a way to know if I did ? I don't really remember, I was trying to install Firefox and Libre Office, so I was following some post that I found on line.

Comment: Could you post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file here? This should help us resolve the problem.

Comment: Dont worry this morning I re-installed Elementary OS again, so the problem is solved. Thanks for your help but since this is my only operating system I couldnt wait long, this is my main computer I needed it working!But thank you !!

Comment: @Mia: Could you please answer your question and mark it as solved?

Comment: This looks like you uninstalled something you really shouldn't have.

Comment: I have this exact same issue, except that my error in the bar at the top says "A problem occurred when checking for updates.". I can run `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` with absolutely no issues, yet I still have the error in the top bar... And I can't even open the Software Centre, probably because of this.