# Software Updater & Software Center apps not launching

Tags: appcenter

**Problem:** Clicking the app-icons does not launch anything.
I've checked out (and tried some of) these solutions:
[software-center-does-not-open-after-update](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2707/software-center-does-not-open-after-update)
[software-center-wont-open](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3062/software-center-wont-open)
[cant-open-software-center](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1544/cant-open-software-center)
But my problem doesn't seem to involve icons, rather:

```
$ software-center
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 25, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 158, in     load_module
    introspection_module = get_introspection_module(namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 271, in get_introspection_module
    module = IntrospectionModule(namespace, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 120, in __init__
repository.require(namespace, version)
gi.RepositoryError: Typelib file for namespace 'GdkPixbuf', version '2.0' not found
```

**Question:** Why aren't they lanuching, and **how to fix it**?

I installed *synaptic* and it works.

This might be connected to my solved problem: [Trouble with APT, DPKG, SYNAPTIC. Linux-Image-thing](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/trouble-with-apt-dpkg-synaptic-linux-image-thing)

Any help is hot :)

Comment: This one ultimately worked for me: edit file: /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme and make sure "Inherits=" line includes icon theme that contains this missing iconm, eg:

Inherits=elementary,Humanity

Comment: `$ cat /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme
[Icon Theme]
Name=elementary
Inherits=elementary,Humanity`
Still ain't launching.
How do I know what theme is missing?

Answer (score 1):

The showed error message is about a namespace not found. Try to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
```

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdk-pixbuf
…
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gdk-pixbuf`

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I've indicated the source package.

Comment: No problem anymore. Heading for the VOID rather than the bloat…